# SAS SQL: Join and Union in Combination to Fill Rows

Tags: sql, join, merge, sas, union

I'm essentially trying to join on two variables, `ID` and `ACCOUNTNUMBER`. Easy. However, the `FULL` dataset has a row of a common `ID` but different `ACCOUNTNUMBER` (note the rename) and `CAR`. I'd like to merge these in and have the `ID` retain these values. See the example data below:

```
DATA FULL;
    LENGTH ID ACCT_FULL CAR $12.;
    INPUT ID $ ACCT_FULL $ CAR $;
    DATALINES;
    A   123 MAZDA
    B   456 FORD
    C   789 CHEVY
    D   777 NISSAN
    ;
RUN;

DATA SUBSET;
    LENGTH ID ACCOUNTNUMBER $12.;
    INPUT ID $ ACCOUNTNUMBER $;
    DATALINES;
    A   123
    B   456
    C   789
    D   012
    ;
RUN;

** THIS QUERY DOES NOT QUITE OUTPUT A DATASET I WANT **;
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
    CREATE TABLE WANT_BAD AS
    SELECT *
    FROM SUBSET AS A
    LEFT JOIN
    FULL(RENAME=(ACCT_FULL=ACCOUNTNUMBER)) AS B
    ON      A.ID = B.ID AND 
            A.ACCOUNTNUMBER = B.ACCOUNTNUMBER;
QUIT;
```

Here is a side-by-side comparison of what I currently have versus what I want:

```
Bad Output:      Want Output:

A   123 MAZDA   |   A   123 MAZDA
B   456 FORD    |   B   456 FORD
C   789 CHEVY   |   C   789 CHEVY
D   012         |   D   012 NISSAN
                |   D   777 NISSAN
```

My question is -- can I add some sort of `UNION` statement to my query to output the data I want? I'd like to do this in SQL rather than data steps because my `FULL` data in real life is massive, and I do not want to read in, sort, and merge using `IN=` statements because it will take much longer.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, because you want to look up the `car` even on rows that don't have matching account numbers.

So, one method is to `union` together all the `id`/`accountnumber` pairs to get all the rows.  Then bring the `car` information back in:

```
proc sql:
    select fs.id, fs.accountnumber, f.car
    from ((select f.id, f.accountnumber from full f) union
          (select s.id, s.acct_full from subset s)
         ) fs left join
         full f
         on f.id = fs.id;
```

Comment: I think you've mixed up which variables are in which datasets which is causing errors. Shouldn't `s.car` be `f.car` since the variable resides in the `FULL` dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with some SQL code that works with the toy data you've provided and seems to give the result you want.  This performs two INNER JOINS - the first one uses the ID from "FULL" and the second join uses the ID from "SUBSET" - with a UNION between the two INNER JOINS.  I don't think this code is efficient, but I couldn't think of any other way to accomplish this.  Test with a sample of your data to see if it works the way you want.

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    /* THIS INNER JOIN MATCHES BY ID ONLY */
    /* CREATES NEWACCT USING ACCOUNT NUMBER FROM "FULL" */
    CREATE TABLE TRY_AGAIN AS

    SELECT A.*, B.*,  
        B.ACCT_FULL AS NEWACCT
    FROM SUBSET AS A
    INNER JOIN 
    FULL  AS B
    ON A.ID = B.ID 

    UNION

    /* THIS INNER JOIN MATCHES BY ID AND AND ACCOUNT NUMBER */
    /* KEEPS ONLY IF ACCOUNT NUMBERS DO NOT MATCH */
    /* CREATES NEWACCT USING THE ACCOUNT NUMBER FROM "SUBSET" */
    SELECT A.*, B.*,  
         A.ACCOUNTNUMBER AS NEWACCT 
    FROM SUBSET AS A
    INNER JOIN 
    FULL  AS B
    ON      A.ID = B.ID AND 
            A.ACCOUNTNUMBER NOT= B.ACCT_FULL

    ORDER BY ID, NEWACCT
;

QUIT;
```